# Check command success in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, dd, cp

I'm currently writing a small script to backup bulks of floppy disks and format them afterward for later use.

I use `dd` to copy the disk's image and `cp` to copy all the files on the disk.

Here are the commands I use to do so:

```
# Copying disk image
dd if="/dev/fd0" of="/path/to/backup/folder" &>/dev/null && sync

# Copying disk files
cp -R "/mnt/floppy/." "/path/to/backup/folder/" &>/dev/null
```

After this process, the script needs to format the floppy disk. My problem is that I want my script to format the floppy disk only if both backup commands (`dd` and `cp`) were successful.

For example, if `dd` couldn't copy all 1.44MB of the floppy disk because of bad blocks, then do not format the floppy disk.

How can I test if both commands were successful (They must be tested seperatly, as I do not always backup both disk's image and files)?

Comment: If you don't always back up both the image and the files, then how do you expect both commands to be successful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do:

```
ok=true
if dd ...; then
  sync
else
  ok=false
fi

cp ... || ok=false

if "$ok"; then
  mformat...
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using bash just add:

```
set -e
```

to the beginning of your script and it will fail whenever any of the commands failed.

Answer (score 3):

Try with:

```
dd <command>
DD_EXIT_STATUS=$?

cp <command>
CP_EXIT_STATUS=$?

if [[ DD_EXIT_STATUS -eq 0 && CP_EXIT_STATUS -eq 0 ]]; then
    format floppy disk
else
    ... other stuff ...
fi
```

Comment: See [Are there naming conventions for variables in shell scripts?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/42847/135943)

Answer (score 2):

You've got some of the syntax you need in your first `dd` command: the `&&` means "only execute what comes next if what comes before succeeds."

The `if` statement takes a command (or series of commands!) and runs them, and then checks the success value at the end.  So you could do:

```
if
    dd etc. etc. && sync &&
    cp etc. etc.
then
    format etc.
fi
```

Comment: Though that would not run `cp` if either `dd` or `sync` failed.

Answer (score 1):

For **error proofing** your commands:

```
execute [INVOKING-FUNCTION] [COMMAND]
```

---

```
execute () {
    error=$($2 2>&1 >/dev/null)

    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "$1: $error"
        exit 1
    fi
}
```

---

**Inspired** in Lean manufacturing:

- [Make errors impossible by design](https://i62.servimg.com/u/f62/16/19/87/90/poka-y10.jpg)
- [Make steps the smallest](https://i62.servimg.com/u/f62/16/19/87/90/kaizen10.png)
- [Finish items one by one](https://i62.servimg.com/u/f62/16/19/87/90/one_pi10.png)
- [Make it obvious to anyone](https://i62.servimg.com/u/f62/16/19/87/90/visual10.png)

Comment: Execute is for SQ statements.

Comment: What's a "SQ statement"?

Comment: Typo, I meant SQL.

Comment: Or you just intended this as a script function?

Comment: Just as a script function, although you can port the concept to any context.

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner test would be

```
command_to_check && command_to_follow_if_previous_one_succeeds
```

You can also use the following one-liner if you want to proceed only if previous command fails.

```
command_to_check || command_to_follow_if_previous_one_fails
```