# Bash can't run command from script: mkdir command not found

Tags: shell-script, cd-command, mkdir

I have separate scripts for tasks in bash. Here is the broken one:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/home/name/
mkdir $PATH
cd $PATH && echo "done."
exit 0
```

Today it broke and first time it simply didn't want to run cd, but created directory. Second time it just said "mkdir command not found." Running this commands exactly with semicolon works fine. What the case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PATH` is an environment variable.  It's what your shell uses to find the commands it is going to run.  More precisely, the `PATH` environment variable contains a colon-separated list of directory names, which are searched in sequence for an executable with the name that you specify when you type a command.  (Unless of course the command you type is a shell builtin, alias or function.)

When you set `PATH` in your script you are "masking" the value of the environment variable with the shell variable of the same name.

The takeaway from this is **don't use all caps names for regular shell variables.**

Since you don't intend an environment variable, just use a lowercase variable name.

Also see:

- [Are there naming conventions for variables in shell scripts?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/42847/135943)

Answer (score 2):

In bash, `PATH` is a special variable that tells `bash` where to look for installed programs. Unless you have a `mkdir` binary in `/home/name/`, it should output `mkdir: command not found` after `PATH` has been set. Use a different variable name to fix this problem.