# How do I join an array of strings where each string has spaces?

Tags: bash, shell-script, quoting, array

My bash script:

```
#!bin/bash
MY_ARRAY=("Some string" "Another string")
function join { local IFS="$1"; shift; echo -e "$*"; }
join "," ${MY_ARRAY[@]}
```

I want the output to be:
`Some string,Another string`.

Instead, I get `Some,string,Another,string`.

What must I change to get the result I want?

Comment: `printf "%s,%s\n" "${MY_ARRAY[@]}"`

Comment: @jasonwryan I corrected a couple typos in my question. Also, is there a solution for when I want to do this for a longer array?

Comment: Add double quotes around `${MY_ARRAY[@]}"`.  See also [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/135943)

Comment: And [Why is printf better than echo?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/135943)

Comment: And [Are there naming conventions for variables in shell scripts?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/42847/135943)

Comment: Clarifying question: what behavior do you want if the array is empty?

Comment: @Wildcard The array will never be empty

Comment: @Username, okay, so if it's empty, the function should output a single newline?

Comment: @Wildcard Correct

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My modified version of your script:

```
#!bin/bash
my_array=("Some string" "Another string")
my_join() {
  [ "$#" -ge 1 ] || return 1
  local IFS="$1"
  shift
  printf '%s\n' "$*"
}
my_join , "${my_array[@]}"
```

Notes:

- Don't use uppercase variable names

  - See [Are there naming conventions for variables in shell scripts?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/42847/135943)
- `join` is a [standard tool](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/join.html).  Use a different name.
- Use quoting

  - See [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/135943)
- Use `printf`, not `echo`

  - See [Why is printf better than echo?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/135943)