# Cat all the files in a git repo without cloning

Tags: git, github

Is there an existing tool which will do something like this:

```
git-cat https://github.com/AbhishekSinhaCoder/Collection-of-Useful-Scripts

then it will run cat on each file in the repo?
```

Something like this works but it doesn't separate the files:

```
curl -s -H "Accept:application/vnd.github.v3.raw" https://api.github.com/repos/AbhishekSinhaCoder/Collection-of-Useful-Scripts/contents/ | 
jq .[].download_url -r | 
xargs curl 2>/dev/null | 
bat
```

Comment: here is one way :/ https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/421570/426217

Comment: If you run `cat` on each file, then they'll all be concatenated.  However, your answer indicates that you don't want that.  What behavior do you want?

Comment: The best behavior would be per file with language recognition in `bat` and when I quit out of the bat pager then it will show the next file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible with a small modification to your command line:

```
curl -s -H "Accept:application/vnd.github.v3.raw" https://api.github.com/repos/AbhishekSinhaCoder/Collection-of-Useful-Scripts/contents/ | 
jq .[].download_url -r | 
xargs -L1 sh -c 'curl "$0" 2>/dev/null | bat'
```

Having said that, if there are a large number of files, you may end up getting rate-limited due to making too many requests, or your results may end up incomplete because they're paginated.  You may wish to do a shallow clone (`git clone --depth=1`) or a partial clone (`git clone --filter=blob:none`) if you'd rather not have the expense of a full clone.

Comment: yeah this works pretty well! Note that you can use `bat --paging=always` to prevent small files from printing directly into the shell