# Duplicate elements of an array except the first and last elements

Tags: bash, array, bash-functions

I have an array, and I would like to repeat each element except the first and last elements.

For example if the array has five elements `1 2 3 4 5`, then after repeating, its elements should be `1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5`.

My bash commands are

```
$ newarr=("${myarr[0]}")
$ for i in $(seq 1 $((${#myarr[@]}-2))) ; do newarr+=( "${myarr[i]}" "${myarr[i]}"); done
$ newarr+=("${myarr[-1]}")
```

Is there a more clear way than mine?

I am also wondering about how to wrap that into a function which takes `myarr` as argument, and returns `newarr`. 
(After creating such a function, I will read  an array from a file, so that each element stores a line in the file, and then call the function on the array. If creating such a function is not a good approach, let me know.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the number of operation down ever so slightly, and skip the call to `seq`:

```
for (( i = 1; i < ${#myarr[@]} - 1; ++i )); do
    newarr+=( "${myarr[i]}" "${myarr[i]}" )
done
newarr=( "${myarr[0]}" "${newarr[@]}" "${myarr[-1]}" )
```

This assumes that `newarr` is empty to start with.  Do `unset newarry` first if it's not.

As a function (this modifies the array that is passed):

```
dup_interal_items () {
    typeset -n arr=$1
    local tmparr

    for (( i = 1; i < ${#arr[@]} - 1; ++i )); do
        tmparr+=( "${arr[i]}" "${arr[i]}" )
    done
    arr=( "${arr[0]}" "${tmparr[@]}" "${arr[-1]}" )
}
```

The *name* of the array is passed into the function and the name-reference variable `arr` is used to access the elements in the array. At the end, the original array is updated to contain the result.

I did it this way rather than *returning* an array as you can only return an exit status from a function. The other approach would have been to pass both the names of an input array *and* an output array and use two name-reference variables in the function.

Or, you could possibly `echo` or `printf` the values in the function (in which case you don't have to construct a new array at all) and then parse that data in the main code.  The function would then be required to be called inside a command substitution.

Note that you *can't* call this function with an array called `arr` due to the particular name scoping rules used by `bash`.  You may want to rename the `arr` variable in the function if this is an issue.

Testing:

```
$ myarr=( 1 2 3 "here we go" )
$ dup_interal_items myarr
$ printf 'Element: %s\n' "${myarr[@]}"
Element: 1
Element: 2
Element: 2
Element: 3
Element: 3
Element: here we go
```

---

To duplicate all lines of a file except for the first and last line:

```
sed -e '1b' -e '$b' -e 'p' <file
```

The `sed` script branches to the end (where there is an implicit print statement) if it's on the first or last line, but prints all other lines (all other lines are therefore both explicitly printed by that last `p` and implicitly printed).

Or, as contributed by don_crissti,

```
sed 'p;1d;$d' <file
```

which explicitly prints each line, then ends the cycle for the first and last line, but prints all other lines implicitly (a second time).

An equivalent `awk` program that does not store more than a single line in memory would be non-trivial to write.

Comment: Thanks. (1) "you can't call this function with an array called arr due to the particular name scoping rules used by bash." Do you mean `arr` declared as `typeset -n arr=$1` inside the function body has global (script-wide) scope? (2) Among the three approaches when creating a bash function, which one do you suggest more or none?

Comment: @Tim (1) A name reference variable can't reference another variable that has the same name as itself (see also [Circular name references in bash shell function, but not in ksh](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/302578)). (2) It depends on what you'd like to do and how you want/need to get there. If the original data was coming from a file, and wasn't used for anything else, I would probably go with reading the array from `sed` instead of reading it and manipulating it. If the resulting data would go to a file, I would not read it into an array at all.

Comment: Thanks. "If the resulting data would go to a file, I would not read it into an array at all." Could you be more specific?

Comment: @Tim Well, if all you want to do is to duplicate the internal lines of a text file and write that to a new file, then there is that `sed` command that could do that for you. Why read it into an array in `bash`?

Comment: I am thinking of writing a shell script, which takes several input files. Each file contains lines of strings in their order.  The script will invoke tsort to figure out the total order among the strings from all the input files, and write these strings to stdout in the total order. So when the script reads one input file, it has to duplicate the strings except the first and last one. Then the script will merge the pairs of strings from all the input files, before invoking tsort on them

Comment: I must be misconstruing `bash` 4.4.23's man page as I read: "The nameref attribute  cannot  be  applied  to  array variables. "_ and that is precisely what you seem to be doing, since what you seem to pass to the function (as `$1`) is the array, not just its name by ref... and then apply `typeset -n arr=$1`. I am seriously confused....   o_O ... ¿?@!

Comment: @Cbhihe No, you are misreading.  It says "Array variables cannot be given the `nameref` attribute.  However, `nameref` variables can reference array variables and subscripted array variables."   In my code, `arr` (in the function) is not an array variable, it's an ordinary variable that I give the `nameref` attribute to. It then references an array variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try also - no function needed -

```
$ ARR=(1 2 3 4 5)
$ IFS=$'\n\t '
$ readarray NEWARR < <(echo "${ARR[*]}" | sed '1!p; $d')
$ echo ${NEWARR[@]}
1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5
```

or even

```
NEWARR=($(printf "%s\n" ${ARR[@]} | sed '1!p; $d'))
```

Comment: Please [avoid using variable names in caps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/673940/9110606) ([except for environment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42849/265604)).

Comment: You should quote variable expansions (`${NEWARR[@]}`) and use `-t` on readarray to remove the trailing newline of each array element.

Answer (score 1):

A solution that accepts newlines:

```
#!/bin/bash
arr=( 1 2 "3 3" $'41\n42' 5 )

readarray -t -d $'\0' newarray < <(printf '%s\0' "${arr[@]}" | sed -z '1!p; $d')

printf '<%s>\n' "${newarr[@]}"
```

Runs as:

```
$ ./script
<1>
<2>
<2>
<3 3>
<3 3>
<41
42>
<41
42>
<5>
```