# How to use variables inside back-quotes

Tags: bash, scripting, io-redirection, variable

I have a bash script that accepts a parameter "$input" and (among other things) directs it into a program and collects the output.

Currently my line is:

```
OUTPUT=`./main.exe < $input`
```

But I get the following error:

```
$input: ambiguous redirect
```

What is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your variable's value probably contains spaces.

You should double quote it:

```
output=$( ./main.exe <"$input" )
```

The `bash` shell requires that the variable, in this context, is quoted and will otherwise perform word-splitting and filename globbing on its value, while other shell may not require this.

Also, note that `$input` here is the pathname of a file that will be connected to the standard input stream of your program, not an argument to `main.exe`  (I might have misunderstood your text, but never the less).  If you want to use `$input` as a command line argument instead, your command would look like

```
output=$( ./main.exe "$input" )
```

Related:

- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766)
- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694)

Also:

- [Have backticks (i.e. `cmd`) in *sh shells been deprecated?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126927)
- [Are there naming conventions for variables in shell scripts?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42847)

Comment: Shouldn't you add quotes around a $() block in the case the output of the command contains spaces? According to [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters) it should

Comment: @Ferrybig: It's not needed when used for variable assignment, the shell will not perform word splitting on it.  See [Shell Parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameters).  This is also mentioned in Gilles answer in the linked question [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68748/237982)

Comment: @Ferrybig As Jesse said, but it would not hurt to always add them if you're uncertain about where and under what circumstances they are actually needed.

Comment: Actually the problem disappeared after I replaced the backticks with the $( ... ) syntax. Thanks!

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi Just changing the backticks to `$( ... )` should not have made a difference. The issue is the quoting of the variable. Using an unquoted variable in `< $input` should still break horribly if the value in `$input` contains spaces.