# Saving each line of file to different variables and use each variable one by one in command line input and output

Tags: shell-script, shell

I am new to shell scripting so apologies if this was asked before.

I have a file coordinates.txt like this:

```
765442
866447
755343
097754
```

I would like to pass each value of each line of the file to a variable and use those values one by one as input in a command line and save that number in part of the file name.
I wrote the following code but not sure if this is the correct way to go...

```
cat coordinates.txt | while read LINE; do
    var="$(echo $LINE)"
    /home/users/scripts/TreeView/TreeView.sh -o $NAME_ALL.chr1.new_estimate.trees.$var --bp_of_interest $var
done
```

so in the output -o each value one at the time is appended to the file name and each value is also used as --bp_of_interest, one at the time

Any suggestion highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What is `$NAME_ALL`? You need to double quote all variable expansions, and `var="$(echo $LINE)"` is better written `var="$LINE"`. Also, remove that `cat` and redirect the file into the loop with `while read ...; done <coordinates.txt`.

Comment: $NAME_ALL is another variable of the beginning of the file name which is already in my environment, it is different from the variables (var) from the file

Comment: sure, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: something like this?: while read LINE; do
    var="$LINE"
    /home/users/scripts/TreeView/TreeView.sh -o $NAME_ALL.chr1.new_estimate.trees."$var" --bp_of_interest "$var"
done <coordinates.txt

Comment: it is working very well, wonderfull

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop is better written as

```sh
PATH=/home/users/scripts/TreeView:$PATH

while IFS= read -r line; do
    TreeView.sh -o "$name_all.chr1.new_estimate.trees.$line" --bp_of_interest "$line"
done <coordinates.txt
```

This changes the following:

- I added `/home/users/scripts/TreeView` to the front of `$PATH`.  This allows us to call `TreeView.sh` without the absolute path prepended to it.
- I deleted the `var` variable, as it was just the same as the value read from the input file.
- I use `IFS= read -r line` because "[Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209123)".
- I used lower-case variable names because "[Are there naming conventions for variables in shell scripts?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42847)".
- I pass the data from the file into the loop with a redirection, because using `cat` in this instance is just not needed.

---

Another way to do the same thing:

```sh
PATH=/home/users/scripts/TreeView:$PATH

xargs -I {} TreeView.sh -o "$name_all.chr1.new_estimate.trees.{}" --bp_of_interest "{}" <coordinates.txt
```

This uses `xargs` to insert the data read from each line of `coordinates.txt` into the arguments of the `TreeView.sh` script in the locations denoted by `{}`.

You could even add `-P n` to the `xargs` command line (e.g. before `-I {}`, where `n` is some number) to run that many parallel instances of the script at once, each with the appropriate data inserted into its command line from `coordinates.txt`.