# What is the term to describe the naming method "MyVariable" (as opposed to "myVariable")?

Tags: bash, terminology, javascript

Variables and procedures in JavaScript are often named via the "camelCase" naming method, as:

- myVariable

Any letter of the only or not-only-but first letter in an expression which acts as a data structure's name or part of a name is lowercased.
Contrarily, from my experience it is somewhat common to uppercase all starting letters of the only or all expressions of a name as:

- MyVariable

**What is the term to describe the data structure Naming method common in Bash?**

Comment: That's not a bash naming convention. That's a naming convention in javascript for classes/constructors. It is also the naming convention in other, even older programming languages for classes eg. Java, C++ etc.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's off-topic. This convention is not common in bash or in any other Unix-related tool.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This naming convention is called PascalCase, or Upper Camel Case or StudlyCase. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Examples_of_multiple-word_identifier_formats) has a list of naming conventions.

Though, I haven't heard of such convention for Bash. It seems to be more open-minded. The only convention I know of for Bash is to use capitalized words for constants. [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42847/are-there-naming-conventions-for-variables-in-shell-scripts) talks about that. TL;DR: pick a convention and stick to it.

Comment: be careful with all caps : they could collide with existing variables (or internal variables). To my knowledge, using a mix of uppercase and lowercase ensure you don't collide with existing common variables (TERM, LINES, etc)

Comment: Most of what I've seen in Bash is snake_case.

Comment: I've seen a few authors use a convention to have the first letter be upper-case for globals, lower-case for locals, regardless of one's choice of animal.

Answer (score 12):

What you describe is sometimes called [PascalCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case#Variations_and_synonyms) - but there is AFAIK no "crystal clear" definition of these typographic writing conventions.

As for the naming of Bash variables, I don't know if using PascalCase is really that common. The only "hard" recommendation I know is *not* to use all uppercase variable names unless you want to export such a variable to an environment variable (there are lots of questions both [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/42847/377345) and [on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/673055/12231187) on that topic). The reason is that (in particular) in Bash, crucial environment variables such as `PATH` are all-uppercase, and you will want to avoid clashing with/superseding these variables by accidentally same-named variables of your script. Since the shell is case sensitive, using lower- or mixed case names for "normal" variables helps avoiding this problem.

**Note** however that it is not that easy if you write scripts for other shells; as noted by @StéphaneChazelas e.g., there are *all-lowercase* variables with special meaning in `zsh` and `csh`, so you are in general well-advised to read the documentation for your shell. For `sh`, `bash` and `ksh`, checking your script with [`shellcheck`](https://shellcheck.net) (also available as standalone program in many Linux distributions) can be a great help as it also looks for (some of) these potential name clashes.

Comment: I think the suggestion to not use all-uppercase comes from most "special" or system-defined env vars being all-uppercase, and the risk of clashing with those. Then again, consider Zsh's all-lowercase `path`, which is special in that it shadows `PATH`...

Comment: @ilkkachu, in zsh scalar special variables are all-uppercase and array special variables are all-lowercase. The tying of the `$PATH` scalar to the `$path` array actually comes from csh a decade before zsh.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, yep, it just means the usual suggestion to use all-lowercase variables to avoid clashes isn't all there is to it. Especially since assigning to `path` easily breaks your whole script. (Or maybe that's a good thing, at least it gets noticed quickly.) And if there's no namespacing, at all, then it's hard to be sure a new version of the shell won't break a script by introducing a new special variable the script used. Doesn't really matter if it's an array or not.

Comment: @ilkkachu, yes very true. I only pointed out that all lower case variables were not limited to `zsh`, nor to `$path` there. In `zsh`, it's a convention for array variables. In `csh`, there are lower case special scalars like those used for options. `bash` used to have similar option variables. That's the ones that were converted to `shopt` options (and explains, though doesn't justify that nonsense with the two sets of options).