# parse command output for use in next command

Tags: shell-script, awk, xargs

I would like to take each line of the output of one gcloud command for use in another gcloud command.

`gcloud container clusters list |grep jesse` (alias gccl)
output:

```
jesse-gke1                us-eastx-x
jesse-gke2                us-eastx-x
```

I need both of these variables (name and region) in the next command.

But when I try to use awk to get the variables I need for the next command, it combines both results into a single variable with 2 lines.

`cluster=$(gccl 2>/dev/null|grep jesse|awk '{print $1}') ; echo $cluster`

Outputs:

```
jesse-gke1
jesse-gke2
```

How can I get both of the output items in a command that would look like:

`gcloud someaction jesse-gke1 zone=us-eastx-x`

and iterate through the results?

Thanks!

Comment: Just a supposition...Did you really remove the double quotation marks from the last command? Meaning `echo $cluster` instead of `echo "$cluster"`. When you require your shell to perform word splitting then quotes are not needed.

Comment: Does `awk` take args from stdin? Try putting xargs in your pipeline just before awk, or just replacing `awk` in your command with `xargs /full/path/to/awk`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

gcloud container clusters list \
    --filter=name:jesse --format="csv[no-heading](name,location)" |
while IFS=, read -r name location; do
    printf 'Resizing NAME: %s, LOCATION: %s\n' "$name" "$location"
    gcloud container clusters resize \
        --zone "$location" "$name" --num-nodes=0 --quiet
done >gccl-script.log
```

This is a rewrite of [your own code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/690662/493832), using a `while` loop rather than a `for` loop.  The `while` loop is used whenever we need to read an indeterminate number of lines in a loop, whereas a `for` loop is used for iterating over a static list.

We also don't need an array as `read` is perfectly happy to read multiple fields into multiple variables.

We use `printf` rather than `echo` to print variable data. The result of `echo` depends on the current state of the shell and on the data outputted.

We can move the redirection of the loop's output to after `done`.

We need to properly quote all expansions to avoid splitting and filename globbing from happening.

I'm using lower-case variable names.

Relevant other questions:

- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803)
- [Are there naming conventions for variables in shell scripts?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42847)
- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694)