# Commands cannot be located after sourcing a bash script

Tags: bash, terminal, path, source, command-not-found

I have a short bash script `cdline` that takes two arguments `PATHS` and `LINE` and changes directory to the respective `LINE` in `PATHS`:

```
#!/bin/bash
#command for changing directory to that in the given line...
#or that of the file in the given line

PATHS=$1
LINE=$2
PATH="$(echo "${PATHS}" | sed -n ${LINE}p)"
PATH="$(/home/gohomology/Scripts/pc_macros/file_system/getdir "${PATH}")"
cd ${PATH}

return 1
```

This calls `getdir` which echoes the given path if its a directory, or the directory that includes the file otherwise.

I know that when calling a bash script normally it creates a subshell, so trying to call the script normally wouldn't do anything. As far as I understand, the solution for this should be sourcing the script, which one can do adding `.` or `source` before calling the script.

This indeed works for changing the directory, however, after doing so my terminal cannot find various commands such as `ls` or `find`, as demonstrated by the following result from my terminal emulator.

```
gohomology@gohomology:~/Desktop$ find . -name "example_file"
./example_dir/example_file

gohomology@gohomology:~/Desktop$ . cdline "$(!!)" 1
. cdline "$(find . -name "example_file")" 1

gohomology@gohomology:~/Desktop/example_dir$ ls
Command 'ls' is available in the following places
 * /bin/ls
 * /usr/bin/ls
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin:/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
ls: command not found

gohomology@gohomology:~/Desktop/example_dir$ find . -name "example_file"
Command 'find' is available in the following places
 * /bin/find
 * /usr/bin/find
The command could not be located because '/bin:/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
find: command not found
```

The command `cd` still works after using `cdline`. I thought that the problem is that I'm stuck within a bash shell, which is why there's `return 1` at the end of `cdline`, but the problem is still existent.

I run bash 5.1.16 and gnome-terminal on Ubuntu 22.04.2.

Comment: Just `declare -p PATH` after every line in your script, and figure out where most of it gets clobbered. You really do not want to assign any intermediate values to PATH. Assign to newPath in your workings, and assign that to PATH as the last step.

Comment: Use lowercase for your variables and you won't get these problems.

Comment: And quote **all** parameter expansions like "${1}", "${2}", "${PATH}". Most likely one of your original path directories has a space in it.

Comment: Thanks!
I changed the variable name from `PATH` to `new_path`, since I saw [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42847/are-there-naming-conventions-for-variables-in-shell-scripts) that zsh might use `path` as a variable name, and for future-proofing.

Comment: Also, why use `return 1`? Nonzero return codes are normally used to indicate errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your script overrides your `PATH` environment variable:

```
PATH="$(echo "${PATHS}" | sed -n ${LINE}p)"
PATH="$(/home/gohomology/Scripts/pc_macros/file_system/getdir "${PATH}")"
```

If you look at the man pages of `bash` you'll see what this variable is used for:

> **PATH**
>
> The search path for commands. It is a colon-separated list of
> directories in which the shell looks for commands (see **COMMAND
> EXECUTION** below).

And then later under the **Command Execution** section:

> If the name is neither a shell function nor a builtin, and contains no
> slashes, **bash** searches each element of the **PATH** for a
> directory containing an executable file by that name.

Since your `PATH` was overridden and now only includes your current working directory, `bash` doesn't know where to look for the command.

The error you see clearly states the problem:

```
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin:/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
```

The reason your `cd` succeeded is that `cd` is not an executable file that `bash` runs, it is a `bash` **builtin** command.

Bottom line, don't use `PATH` for a variable name in the script, use a different name that's not used by `bash`.

Answer (score 1):

`PATH` is a special variable that tells the shell where to look for commands, don't use it as a temporary variable in your script.

from `man bash.1`

> PATH
>
> The search path for commands. It is a colon-separated list of directories in which the shell looks for commands (see COMMAND EXECUTION below). A zero-length (null) directory name in the value of PATH indicates the current directory. A null directory name may appear as two adjacent colons, or as an initial or trailing colon. The default path is system-dependent, and is set by the administrator who installs bash. A common value is ``/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin''.